# Storing ActionLink in model or RouteValueDictionary in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wish to store an action link in the model.
Something like

```
public MvcHtmlString ActionLink_New
{
    get { return Html.ActionLink("new", "Edit", "News", new { Area = "Admin" }, null); }
}
```

It appears the model needs a webviewpage context.

Failing that, I thought I would store just the route values.

```
public RouteValueDictionary[] RouteValue_New 
{
    get { return new RouteValueDictionary[] { Area = "Admin" }; }
}

//View
@Html.ActionLink("new", "Edit", "News", Model.RouteValue_New, null)
```

The `Area` in the property is red. Is either or both scenario achievable. What do i need to add to get this to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public object RouteValue_New
    {
        get { 
            return new { Area = "Admin" }; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct way. Also, the model should have no connection to the WebPageView. thank you for helping